# Just how many tickets did John Wayne and Clark Gable sell?

Tags: box-office

I was reading the Wikipedia article on [John Wayne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wayne) and noticed the following quote:

> Between 1926 and 1976, Wayne appeared in over 170 motion pictures, and became one of America's biggest box office stars. Only Clark Gable sold more tickets than Wayne, although the ticket prices were not commensurate since, although both actors started their careers at the same time, Gable's career height preceded Wayne's by approximately fifteen years.

Just how many tickets did these two men sell? Are they close or did Clark Gable blow him out of the water (presumably) due to the success of *Gone With the Wind*?

Comment: Not sure this is knowable especially since the Wikipedia statement is, apparently, **unsourced**.

Comment: @Paulie_D I agree it might not be easy to find, but I believe "unknowable" is too harsh. Surely there are records somewhere. After all taxes, royalties, residuals, etc. had to be paid so some sort of accounting was taken. I agree it is unsourced. If there was a source then I wouldn't have needed to ask the question here. Are you trying to suggest that the question would be more suited to skeptics.se and therefore should be migrated?

Comment: *"Surely there are records somewhere"* - maybe, but good luck finding them after 60-90 years...assuming they do *actually* exist.

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't understand the constructive point of your comments. It seems like you're saying something along the lines of, "this question is impossible to answer so don't waste your time." Are you trying to be helpful or just rain on the parade? If you're just going to be a source of unconstructive negativity why don't you just delete your comments and move on?

Comment: I'm trying to point out that we don't even know what "more tickets" means...does it mean the actual number of butts in seats (I *really* doubt that information exists) or **box-office revenue**...where some analysis *has* been done. [**Wayne** - TOTAL BOX OFFICE GROSS: $8,253,350,000 (Adjusted in 2016 USD)](https://boxofficemadness.wordpress.com/2017/07/12/john-wayne-film-grosses-1930-1976/) & [**Gable** - TOTAL BOX OFFICE GROSS: $8,314,646,000 (Adjusted in 2016 USD)](https://boxofficemadness.wordpress.com/2017/06/30/clark-gable-film-grosses-1931-1961/)

Comment: @Paulie_D my assumption was they were talking about butts in seats since the quote separates out ticket prices. That being said box office gross is directly tied to butts in seats and if the ticket prices have been adjusted for inflation then this might be a useful proxy. If you post those links with a short discussion about seats then I'll up-vote you. It's a shame that [Box Office Mojo](http://www.boxofficemojo.com/people/?view=Actor&sort=sumgross&p=.htm) doesn't seem to include adjusted stats for an easy historical comparison between actors and their box office takes.

Comment: @Paulie_D although I don't know how accurate the numbers in your links are. [Box Office Mojo](http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?page=releases&id=gonewiththewind.htm) gives roughly half the take for the last two releases of *Gone With the Wind*. I don't think inflation was quite that high over the last ~28 years.